# Use NSCache in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscache

I m using **NSCache** to save data for offline mode in app,but im not getting how to save that cache object in **user default** so that if app runs again data  will be there in cache.I have created NSCache object in a Singleton Class.
Any idea or alternate solution will surely be appreciated.

Comment: `NSCache` is used to store objects in memory that are expensive to create and may be needed again, but can be recreated if needed; NSCache may evict an item without warning so you must always be prepared for a cache miss; I.e. it may return nil. Given all of this it doesn't make sense to persist an instance of NSCache; you would simply repopulate the cache from the original objects when required

Comment: I would read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542707/save-nscache-contents-to-disk